# Proper way to read from a texture in a compute shader which uses a storage texture

Tags: textures, framebuffer, compute-shader, webgpu, wgsl

I've been searching for different resources and it seems to not be possible to read from a storage texture and then write back to it. That's why I've tried to use 2 separate textures: one as `texture_storage_2d<rgba16float, write>` and a second one as `texture_2d<f32>`. However, when I use them in the same (or even in 2 separate) bind group(s), I got this error I can't quite understand:

```
[Texture "Framebuffer Texture"] usage (TextureUsage::
(TextureBinding|TextureUsage::8000000)) includes writable usage and another usage in the same synchronization scope.
 - While validating compute pass usage.

[Invalid CommandBuffer] is invalid.
 - While calling [Queue].Submit([[Invalid CommandBuffer]])
```

According to this [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/wgpu/comments/x5z4tb/writing_to_a_texture_from_a_compute_shader/), it should be possible even though a comment reported an error which might be similar..?

In another [example](https://gist.github.com/bellbind/8318c595fb1464bfefa2827b0b55667a) an `array<f32>` is used as a storage buffer and then as an input to read pixel data info from.

And in [webgpu-samples](https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/samples/cornell#./radiosity.wgsl), an `array<atomic<u32>>` seems to be used for the same purpose, although it looks much more complicated for some reason.

Also, according to the webgpufundamentals [blog post](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-storage-textures.html), there IS a way to have a `read_write` storage texture, but only 3 formats `r32*` can be used and I wasn't able to find any example with those.

I'm quite confused right now, so hopefully someone can bring some clarity to this whole read-write texture business. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks! Anyway, this is how I'm currently doing it:

```js
    const framebuffer = this.device.createTexture({
      size: [Config.width, Config.height],
      label: 'Framebuffer Texture',
      format: 'rgba16float',
    
      usage:
        GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT |
        GPUTextureUsage.STORAGE_BINDING |
        GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING
    });
    
    const computeBindGroupLayout = this.device.createBindGroupLayout({
      label: 'Compute Bind Group Layout',
    
      entries: [{
        binding: 0,
        visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE,
        storageTexture: { format: framebuffer.format }
      }, {
        binding: 1,
        texture: {},
        visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE
      }]
    });
    
    
    this.computeBindGroup = this.device.createBindGroup({
      layout: computeBindGroupLayout,
      label: 'Compute Bind Group',
    
      entries: [{
        binding: 0,
        resource: framebuffer.createView()
      }, {
        binding: 1,
        resource: framebuffer.createView()
      }]
    });
```

```
    // Workgroup size:
    override size: u32;
    
    @group(0) @binding(0)
    var framebuffer: texture_storage_2d<rgba16float, write>;
    
    @group(0) @binding(1)
    var texture: texture_2d<f32>;
    
    @compute @workgroup_size(size, size)
    fn mainCompute(@builtin(global_invocation_id) globalInvocation: vec3u)
    {
      let color = textureLoad(texture, globalInvocation.xy, 0);
      textureStore(framebuffer, globalInvocation.xy, color);
    }
```

And this is how I'd like to sample the output texture in the fragment shader
(works well with the framebuffer when `texture` is not passed and `textureLoad` is not used):

```
    @group(0) @binding(0) var texture: texture_2d<f32>;
    @group(0) @binding(1) var textureSampler: sampler;
    
    @fragment
    fn mainFragment(@location(0) coords: vec2f) -> @location(0) vec4f
    {
      return textureSample(texture, textureSampler, coords);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a storage buffer to duplicate output color information after each compute pass as an input for the next pass. As far I understand, the use of a framebuffer storage texture could be avoided now in the fragment shader, but that will require to modify that shader in order for it to map this storage buffer values to pixel colors and add a frame resolution uniform to achieve that. Since I wanted to reuse an already implemented render pipeline (which leverages a "framebuffer" texture), I've opted for the first option.

```js
const computeBindGroupLayout = this.device.createBindGroupLayout({
  label: 'Compute Bind Group Layout',

  entries: [/*
    Bindings 0 - 2...
  */ {
    binding: 3,
    buffer: { type: 'storage' },
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE
  }, {
    binding: 4,
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE,
    storageTexture: { format: this.imageTexture.format }
  }]
});

const colorBuffer = this.device.createBuffer({
  label: 'Compute Color Buffer',
  usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE,
  size: Image.width * Image.height * 16
});

this.computeBindGroup = this.device.createBindGroup({
  layout: computeBindGroupLayout,
  label: 'Compute Bind Group',

  entries: [/*
    Entries 0 - 2...
  */ {
    binding: 3,
    resource: { buffer: colorBuffer }
  }, {
    binding: 4,
    resource: this.imageTexture.createView()
  }]
});
```

```
@group(0) @binding(3)
var<storage, read_write> colorBuffer: array<vec3f>;

@group(0) @binding(4)
var framebuffer: texture_storage_2d<rgba16float, write>;

@compute @workgroup_size(size, size)
fn mainCompute(@builtin(global_invocation_id) globalInvocation: vec3u)
{
  let res = vec2f(textureDimensions(framebuffer));
  let coord = vec2f(globalInvocation.xy);

  if (all(coord < res))
  {
    let bufferIndex = u32(coord.x + coord.y * res.x);
    var color = colorBuffer[bufferIndex];

    colorBuffer[bufferIndex] = doSomeMagic(color);
    textureStore(framebuffer, globalInvocation.xy, vec4f(colorBuffer[bufferIndex], 1.0));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I've managed to achieve this by using [`GPUCommandEncoder:copyTextureToTexture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GPUCommandEncoder/copyTextureToTexture) method. So at the setup time it looks like this:

```js
this.framebuffer = this.device.createTexture({
  size: [Config.width, Config.height],
  label: 'Framebuffer Texture',
  format: 'rgba16float',

  usage:
    GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT |
    GPUTextureUsage.STORAGE_BINDING |
    GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING |
    GPUTextureUsage.COPY_SRC
});

this.imageTexture = this.device.createTexture({
  size: [Config.width, Config.height],
  label: 'GPU Computed Image',
  format: 'rgba16float',

  usage:
    GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT |
    GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING |
    GPUTextureUsage.COPY_DST
});

const computeBindGroupLayout = this.device.createBindGroupLayout({
  label: 'Compute Bind Group Layout',

  entries: [{
    binding: 0,
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE,
    storageTexture: { format: this.framebuffer.format }
  }, {
    binding: 1,
    buffer: { type: 'uniform' },
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE
  }, {
    binding: 2,
    texture: {},
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE
  }, {
    binding: 3,
    sampler: {},
    visibility: GPUShaderStage.COMPUTE
  }]
});

this.computeBindGroup = this.device.createBindGroup({
  layout: computeBindGroupLayout,
  label: 'Compute Bind Group',

  entries: [{
    binding: 0,
    resource: this.framebuffer.createView()
  }, {
    binding: 1,
    resource: { buffer: this.tracerUniformBuffer }
  }, {
    binding: 2,
    resource: this.imageTexture.createView()
  }, {
    binding: 3,
    resource: this.sampler
  }]
});
```

And in the render loop:

```js
const commandEncoder = this.device.createCommandEncoder();
const computePass = commandEncoder.beginComputePass();

// Update uniforms, set pipeline, set bind group and dispatch workgroups...

computePass.end();

const { width, height } = Config;

commandEncoder.copyTextureToTexture(
  { texture: this.framebuffer },
  { texture: this.imageTexture },
  { width, height }
);
```

And then in the compute shader:

```
// Workgroup size:
override size: u32;

@group(0) @binding(0)
var framebuffer: texture_storage_2d<rgba16float, write>;

@group(0) @binding(1)
var<uniform> tracerUniform: TracerUniform;

@group(0) @binding(2)
var texture: texture_2d<f32>;

@group(0) @binding(3)
var textureSampler: sampler;

@compute @workgroup_size(size, size)
fn mainCompute(@builtin(global_invocation_id) globalInvocation: vec3u)
{
  var color = textureLoad(texture, globalInvocation.xy, 0).rgb;
  // color = doSomeMagic(color);
  textureStore(framebuffer, globalInvocation.xy, vec4f(color, 1.0));
}
```

So didn't even have to change my fragment shader which is still reading from the same framebuffer, updated every frame. But I don't know.., doesn't feel quite right to me. I mean `commandEncoder.copyTextureToTexture` is very handy, but couldn't that be potentially slower than manually replicating the same operation in the compute shader and do not queue `commandEncoder` every frame..?